# React native navigation prop not being passed to the function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React native navigation from stack navigator is not being passed down to the Restaurantsscreen function

This is the function which has to use naviagtion but it cant

```
    export const RestaurantsScreen = ({navigation}) => (
      <SafeArea>
    
      
        <View style={{"backgroundColor": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)"}}>  
         
        <FlatList
          data={[
            { name: 1 }
           
         
          ]}
          renderItem={(item) =>{return (  
             
            <Pressable onPress={ ()=>console.log(navigation)}>
              
             
               <RestaurantInfoCard />
    
            </Pressable>
            
       
        
          );
          }}
```

and these are the functions where stack navigator is defined

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Screentwo} /> // this screen is currently loaded and the screentwo is  importing the Restaurants screen function inside it as a component
      
      </Stack.Navigator>
      
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Kindly help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions :

- Past the `navigation` props from the `Screentwo` to you're child component `RestaurantsScreen`
- Used the `useNavigation` hooks directly in your `RestaurantsScreen` component (see link for this hook : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/)

Example of the first solution:

```
//Screentwo inherit navigation props direclty, as this component is called in your Stack.Navigator
export const Screentwo = ({navigation}) => { 

    return( 
         //As RestaurantsScreen is not called directly in your Stack.Navigator, 
         //this component will not inherit navigation props, 
         //you need to past manually navigation props from Screentwo in this way
         <RestaurantsScreen navigation={navigation} /> 
    ) 
}
```

Example of the second solution with `useNavigation` :

```
//Directly in your RestaurantsScreen component
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

//No need to import navigation props
export const RestaurantsScreen = () => { 

    //Call useNavigation, and navigation can be used in the exact same way as if you past it as a props
    const navigation = useNavigation()

    return (
         <SafeArea>
              the rest of your code here
         </SafeArea>
    )

}
```

Comment: Hi, how do i pass the navigation props from screentwo to child component? i am basically calling   <RestaurantsScreen /> inside the view of screentwo

Comment: I've update my answer with example on how to implement both solutions